# How do I get the duration of an animation in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How does one get the duration of an animation in three.js?

Let's say we have a sample like this one,

```
var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene)
gltf.animations.forEach((clip)) => {
 let animation = mixer.clipAction(clip)
animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce)
animation.clampWhenFinished = true
animation.play()
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could also upvote my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration of your animation can be returned by `clip.duration`, inside of the forEach loop. You can find out more about this on the three.js docs on the AnimationClip. Keep in mind that this is returned in seconds.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationClip.duration

Comment: There seems to be a wee bit problem with that. When I use THREE.Clock() to get Duration of animation like starting the clock when animation plays and stopping it on mixer's finished event. It says 2.1 Seconds whereas clip.duration returns 1.66 seconds.

Comment: The clock has some overlay. `clip.duration` returns the correct value

Comment: The clock needs to take some time in order to start it's counter. The clip duration knows the time before even running the animation, which is why it gives the exact time.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect now. Just one more thing. How do I make the animation run in stutter? This maybe weird but I'm required to do so. I tried the fps approach, although that did work but it also affects the Orbit Controls, as it affects the whole scene. I just want to change animation's frame rate.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert on stutter. It would be great, though, if you could accept this answer as correct.

Comment: Consider opening a new question to change frame rate